# What's the purpose of repeating this scene twice?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-father

In *The Father (2020)*, the night Anne came home with the chicken from the market, Anthony overhears her
and Paul having an argument over the canceled holiday to Italy at the dining table.
Anne invites Anthony to dinner. In the middle of the dinner Anthony gets up and goes
to the kitchen to fetch a chicken. When he returns to the dining table **he overhears
the same previous dialogue** between Anne and Paul about the canceled holiday.

What's the purpose of repeating this scene twice?

Comment: I haven't seen the movie, but from what little I know the whole movie is about the unreliability of the father's memory due to his dementia and whole sections of the movie try to let the viewer experience this from the father's POV.